# How do models and associations work in relation to foreign keys?

Tags: node.js, model, angular-cli, sequelize.js

I am looking at some Angular code that processes the javascript files of some models and I came upon this segment of the code that seems to assign associations with each of the models.

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});
```

The code in the models seem to assign an associate to UploadAnalyte of model UploadBatch and repeats this for the two other models. I am wondering how the code above links model data to the model code below, since the sql data structure is not entirely clear.

```
UploadAnalyte.associate = (models) => {
    UploadAnalyte.belongsTo(models.UploadBatch, {
        foreignKey: 'batch_row_id'
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same Angular?

Comment: It's Angular CLI 6.2.3 for Node.

Comment: Angular is client side, you are showing server side code.